# Apt returning 404 error on apt-get install

Tags: apt

I am getting the below error when trying to test a new repo

```
Failed to fetch http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1//data1/repos/lucid/repo/some_package.deb 404 not found.
```

My sources.list file contains entry is as follows

```
deb http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1 lucid/
```

repo1 is a symlink to /data1/repos

Also my repo directory structure is as follows:

Debs => /data1/repos/lucid/repo

Release files => /data1/repos/lucid/dists/lucid/Release and Release.gpg

Package and Packages.gz in /data1/repos/lucid

Comment: Please make sure `sudo apt-get update` works fine first. Your repo list has to be updated.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith apt-get update is working but still its ignoring the Release and Release.gpg files as a result I am not able to authenticate the packages plus getting the above error;It seems like a issue with the repo directory structure.Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't the sources.list entry be `deb http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1/repos lucid/`?

Comment: @muru repo1 is a symlink to /data1/repos and lucid is a directory under that

Comment: @ninjaas sorry i got confused. Shouldn't it be `deb http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1/repos/lucid lucid/` then? The goal is to be able to look up `dists/$channel` relative to the URL. You can check using `apt-get update --print-uris`.

Comment: @ninjaas argh copy-pasta error: should be `repo1/lucid lucid/`

Comment: @muru But why do I need to specify `repos/lucid` when repo1 is already a symlink to `/data1/repos`?

Comment: @ninjaas as i said, copy-pasta error. That should have been `repo1/lucid`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the source entry:

```
deb URI CHANNEL [SECTION]
```

Apt will look at:

- `URI/dists/CHANNEL/Release` for release information
- Use URIs from the Release information for the Packages file (typically `URI/dists/CHANNEL/[SECTION/]TYPE-ARCH/`)
- Use URIs from the Packages file for the actual packages (typically `URI/pool/SECTION/*/`)

You made a rather confusing situation by using the CHANNEL in the URI. That is, where one would usually see

```
http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1/ubuntu
```

You have used

```
http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1/lucid
```

So the complete source line would be:

```
deb http://myrepo.blah.com/repo1/lucid lucid
```

You can verify this by using the `--print-uris` option with `apt`:

```
apt-get update --print-uris
```